# Checking IE Window Status of a Manually opened IE Window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

HI all,

I am trying to script some actions on a web based application by using simple SendKeys in a .VBS script.

The only problem i have come accross is the fact that i have to put Sleeps in the script to wait for pages loading.

I was wondering if there was a was i could monitor an IT window and wait for it to finish loading instead of using a Sleep command.

This would reduce un-needed pauses (if the system is running fast for once)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IE has a 'Busy' property.

When the page is loading: Busy = true
When the page is ready: Busy = false

If you use a Do While loop until Busy = false your script will wait until the page is loaded

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i believe that that property is only accessible when my script called the IE window. The windows i want to check were not called by my script.

Comment: Ok if your script is not opening the IE window, you can get the windows 'HWND' value you should be able to referance it using that, then check the 'ReadyState = 4'